# Documentum REST API issue

Tags: rest, postman, documentum6.5

I have successfully installed Documentum REST API in my environment. When I go to http://localhost:8080/dctm-rest/repositories I am able to see the repositories successfully. But when I when I try to open any cabinet URL there, it prompts for username password.

I put a password there and it works fine.

But when I send the request using Postman it shows this error

```
"status": 401,
"code": "E_GENERAL_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR",
"message": "Authentication failed.",
"details": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
```

and when sending with Authorization in the format 
Authorization : Basic (base64 value of  "username:password")

it shows

```
"status": 400,
"code": "E_INPUT_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENTS_PARAM",
"message": "Illegal argument {0} provided with value {1}.",
"details": "Parameter conditions \"dql\" not met for actual request 
parameters: "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried few links and used Basic Auth, which worked!
[image]

Comment: which credentials you are using for this . i am getting authentication error

Comment: The same which you use to login to webtop or any other tool when Accessing Documentum

Comment: I have some db credentials and the opentext login credentials . is it one of them?

Comment: If you have access to Documentum using webtop then you need to enter those credentials. Try using dB cred also.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to turn on the Interceptor to make proxy-authenticated request so that it has the same request context as of browser.

Comment: How can I do that?